Running Sagemaker PySparkProcessor in cluster mode
I am trying to launch PySparkProcessor in cluster mode using the below piece of code. However when I check the cloudwatch log, my job is still running in client mode. Kindly help in fixing the issue.I tried with "spark.submit.deployMode":"cluster" in properties. But not working.
from sagemaker.spark.processing import PySparkProcessor
import sagemaker

default_bucket = "bucket-xxxxxxxxxxx"
sagemaker_session = sagemaker.Session(default_bucket=default_bucket)
spark_processor = PySparkProcessor(
    base_job_name = "sm-spark-vamsi-test",
    role = vamsi_aws_role,
    instance_count = 2, 
    sagemaker_session = sagemaker_session,
    instance_type = 'ml.m5.xlarge',
    max_runtime_in_seconds = 1200,
    configuration_location = "s3_location/sagemaker_config_loc"
)

pyspark_application_code = "s3_location/test.py"
spark_event_logs_s3_uri = "s3_location/logs"
submit_py_files = ["s3_location/python_test.zip"]
# Add your spark configurations in the below configuration block.
configuration = [{
 "Classification": "spark-defaults",
 "Properties": {
                "spark.submit.deployMode":"cluster"
}}]

# Launching PySparkProcessor
spark_processor.run(
    submit_app = pyspark_application_code,
    spark_event_logs_s3_uri = spark_event_logs_s3_uri,
    configuration = configuration,
    submit_py_files = submit_py_files,
    submit_files = ["s3_location/dev.properties"]
)

Cloudwatch Log in which we can see the spark-submit is running in client mode after running the above code snippet.

How to launch PySparkProcessor in cluster mode?
